# Sqlite database non-ascii character error with python SQLalchemy library

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

When i use sqlite3 database with sqlalchemy library, i got this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) 
You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can
interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). 
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application 
to Unicode strings. 
u'INSERT INTO model_pair (user, password) VALUES (?, ?)' ('\xebE\xc2\xe4.\t312874@gg.com', '123456')
```

and here is some test data:

```
 呆呆 3098920@gg.com        11111                                                             
  è?“è¨€    9707996@gg.com        11111 
wwwj55572@gg?€?       11111
```

***I have configured database encoding as utf-8 or gbk but neither success
when insert, i try str.decode('gbk'), it will stuck on char like € and get error like above.***

anyone tell me how get around this error ?

Comment: For those experiencing the same issue, please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876342/sqlalchemy-programmingerror-can-interpret-8-bit-bytestrings/38513385#38513385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change `'\xebE\xc2\xe4.\t312874@gg.com'` to `u'\xebE\xc2\xe4.\t312874@gg.com'`

also, you could try to do `'\xebE\xc2\xe4.\t312874@gg.com'.decode("utf-8")`, but it gives an error "invalid continuation byte", perhaps your string is not valid utf-8 after all?

btw, do mention is you are running python 2.x or 3.x, there is a difference.

Comment: i use python2.7 and i am trying to insert sql statement, instead of using ORM model to import data. Behide the science cause trouble

Comment: did you try `u'\x...'` or `u"\N{EURO SIGN}"`?