# sqlalchemy - (ProgrammingError) can interpret 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm using do SqlAlchemy with python 2.7.6

I came across:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytes
>   trings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like
>   text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your
>   application to Unicode strings. u'INSERT INTO algoritimo ("nomeAlgoritimo", clas
>   se, "estruturaDados", "complexidadePiorCaso", "complexidadeMedioCaso", "complexi
>   dadeMelhorCaso", "complexidadeEspacos", "pseudoAlgoritimo") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)' ('Ordena\xe7\xe3o Sele\xe7\xe3o', 'Algoritmo de oderna\xe7\xe3o', '
>   Array, Listas ligadas', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n) total, O(1) auxiliar
>   ', '')

I use:

> Base = declarative_base()
>   engine = create_engine('sqlite:///classificacao_pesquisa.db')

```
class Algoritimo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'algoritimo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nomeAlgoritimo = Column(String(50))
    classe = Column(String(250))
    estruturaDados = Column(String(50))
    complexidadePiorCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeMedioCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeMelhorCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeEspacos = Column(String(50))
    pseudoAlgoritimo = Column(String(4000))
```

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same issue and here is the solution;

[Coercing Encoded Strings to Unicode](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#typedecorator-recipes)

As stated in the above documentation db.Unicode type would not be enough, you still have to send the string in the form of u'some string';

> A common source of confusion regarding the Unicode type is that it is
>   intended to deal only with Python unicode objects on the Python side,
>   meaning values passed to it as bind parameters must be of the form
>   u'some string' if using Python 2 and not 3. The encoding/decoding
>   functions it performs are only to suit what the DBAPI in use requires,
>   and are primarily a private implementation detail.

So you can create your own Type using the TypeDecorator;

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, Unicode

class CoerceUTF8(TypeDecorator):
    """Safely coerce Python bytestrings to Unicode
    before passing off to the database."""

    impl = Unicode

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = value.decode('utf-8')
        return value
```

Usage:

```
some_value = db.Column(CoerceUTF8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`db.Column(db.UnicodeText(64))`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UnicodeText) where you need `Unicode string type`.

Comment: I testing [nomeAlgoritimo = Column(UnicodeText(50))] but I not have success.

Comment: Then set approptiate text_factory for sqlite  engine.connect().connection.connection.text_factory = str

Comment: But, I use sqlAlchemy:  engine = create_engine('sqlite:///classificacao_pesquisa.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Comment: https://github.com/afonsoaugusto/classificacaoEPesquisa/blob/master/Projeto_2bimestre/controller.py

Comment: I see only two possible solutions...use Unicode string type or use text_factory = str, also useful link, evergreen this days: farmdev.com/talks/unicode.

Comment: It was not clear the proposal. 
I've committed a few changes. 
The error occurs because I try interir this character: ^

Comment: I using: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals Great.

Comment: @That_User: Thanks to you. `engine.connect().connection.connection.text_factory=str` works for me.